# Import CSV file into Mysql DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I found the below php code online which I am using to import csv files into MySql tables. The code works fine except that it doesn't seem to work properly when a string field is enclosed in " " (double quotes).

For example, if I have the following line in my CSV file

> field1,field2,"This, breaks", field3

It will import field1 and field2 fine but then when it gets to the next field enclosed in quotes it will import **"This** into field 3 and then **breaks"** into field 4  with the quotations. How can I edit my code below so that it will not break a string that is enclosed in quotes into separate fields when it finds a comma. I also don't want the "" (quotes) to show in my database table fields.

```
//loop through the csv file and insert into database
        do {
            if ($data[0]) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts_tmp (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
                    (
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                    )
                ");
```

Comment: Are you using fgetcsv() to read the file?

Comment: And why not simply use LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: yes, while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

Comment: I'm going to look into LOAD DATA INFILE now. Haven't used it before. Thanks.

Comment: how come your field delimitor is not efficient? there should be a way to `explode("\t",file_get_contents('your_file.csv'))`

Comment: Your enclosure should be a `"`, not a `'`: `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'));` not `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - It's not efficient because his enclosure value is incorrect

Comment: Importing a file line by line can get really slow. I do recommend using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, too. With it you can import 280k rows or more in a second or two. The line by line approach would take you half an hour :D

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html do look really good. look it up @pokerplayer

Comment: something something something sql injection. something something don't use mysql_* functions or at least use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @MarkBaker That did it! Works perfectly now. I need this for some data updates that I have to finish now so I will leave as is for now but I willmost likely be switching over to LOAD DATA INFILE since there might be some larger files that will need to be imported in the near future. Thanks again!